Difference in handling zero after decimal between web and android
I noticed Flutter has different ways of handling zero after decimals between the web and Android.
for example:
Double Z = 0;
Double Y = 0;
Double X = 0;
Double W = 0;

Z = Y + X * (4 - W));

Print (Z);
\\Output in web: XX
\\Output in the web: XX.0

I tried:
Z = double.parse(Z.toStringAsFixed(2));

Didn't do anything.
I had to parse to int to make it show XX rather than XX.0 on Android.
Parsing to int is troublesome, truncating the numbers is not ideal either.
Why is there a difference between Web and Android?
How can I make sure all of the numbers don't show zero after decimals in one code without losing precision if the number after decimal is not zero? (I have > 50 variables).
Thank you.

just use Z.toStringAsFixed(0) for no decimal without double.parse as it will return number with decimals!

Still not working.
Z = Y + X * (4 - W));
Z.toStringAsFixed(0);
\Output is XX.0

it should work. if it still doesn't work, you might want to convert to int and then output.

This question is similar to: How do you round a double in Dart to a given degree of precision AFTER the decimal point?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It doesn't answer why the web displays the output differently from Android. Also, converting to int might lead to losing precision if the number is after the decimal is not 0.

"Also, converting to int might lead to losing precision if the number is after the decimal is not 0" - so what result do you expect if any X, Y or Z is not an integer value?

If the result is 35.5, I want the result to be 35.5. If it is 35, then 35, not 35.0.
The web version removes the unnecessary zeros, but the Android version doesn't.

`void main() {
final numbers = [
35.0, 35.1, 35.2, 35.3, 35.4, 35.5, 35.6, 35.7, 35.8, 35.9, 36.0,
];
for (final d in numbers) {
print(removeZero(d));
}
}
String removeZero(double d) => d % 1 == 0? d.toInt().toString() : d.toStringAsFixed(1);`

You get different results for the web and for the Dart VM because on the web you're transpiling to JavaScript, JavaScript doesn't have separate int and double types, so type information is lost and heuristics are used to try to recover the type.  You have numbers that look like they should be integers, so they're printed as integers.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858300/
